# Why does AJAX div loads html, but doesn't call javascript from the other html?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've spent so long trying to get this multiple-page via ajax to work.

First I used this tutorial: http://webdesign.torn.be/tutorials/javascript/prototype/page-loading/

For some reason, the javascript call doesn't work for me:

Here's my layout.

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>The Venue - New Student building</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightwindow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />   

 <script type="text/javascript" src="miniTab.js"></script>
 <link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 // <![CDATA[
                document.observe('dom:loaded', function () {
  var newsCat = document.getElementsByClassName('newsCat');
  for (var i = 0; i < newsCat.length; i++) {
   $(newsCat[i].id).onclick = function () {
    getCatPage(this.id);
   }
  }
 });

 function getCatPage(id) {
  var url = 'load-content4.php';
  var rand   = Math.random(9999);
  var pars   = 'id=' + id + '&rand=' + rand;
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Request( url, {method: 'get', parameters: pars, onLoading: showLoad, onComplete: showResponse} );
 }

 function showLoad () {
  $('newsContent').style.display = 'none';
  $('newsLoading').style.display = 'block';
 }

 function showResponse (originalRequest) {
  var newData = originalRequest.responseText;
  $('newsLoading').style.display = 'none';
  $('newsContent').style.display = 'block';  
  $('newsContent').innerHTML = newData;
 }
 // ]]>
 </script>
         <!-- blablablablbaalblabalbalblablablabla other stuff -->

</head>

<body>



<div id="newsContainer" style="background-image: url(images/menuGradient.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100%;" align="center"> 

<table width="980" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#1B1B1B">

<tr><td width="960" align="center" background="http://bytes.com/images/menuGradient.png" >


    <div id="newsCategoriesContainer">
<ul id="miniflex" >
 <span>
    <li><div class="newsCat" id="tabHome"><a class="active" title="">Home</a></div></li>
        <li><div class="newsCat" id="tabInformation"><a title="">Information</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="newsCat" id="tabGallery"><a>Gallery</a></div></li>
        <li><a href="/archives/" title="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/the-language-in-the-lab/" title="">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/demo/animated-minitabs/" title="">Sitemap</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/" title="">Contact us</a></li>
 </span>
</ul></div>


1111111111111111111 blablablabla

      <tr><td width="960" valign="top" align="left">
    <div style="width: 960px; position: relative;">

  <div id="newsLoading" align="center"><img src="loading_indicator.gif" title="Loading..." alt="Loading..." border="0" vspace="100" /></div>

    <div>
        <div id="newsContent"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**loadcontent4.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />


</head>
<body>
<?php
function stringForJavascript($in_string) {
   $str = ereg_replace("[\r\n]", " \\n\\\n", $in_string);
   $str = ereg_replace('"', '\\"', $str);
   return $str;
}
switch($_GET['id']) {
 case 'tabHome':
  include('Home.html');
  break;
 case 'tabInformation':
  include('deleteme_frameContent1.html');
  break;
 case 'tabGallery':
  include('Gallery.html');
  break;
 default:
  $content = 'There was an error.';

} 
print stringForJavascript($content);
usleep(600000);
?>

</body>

</html>
```

**Gallery.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Gallery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/lightwindow.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightwindow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />   


</head>

<body>

<a href="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/side1.jpg" class="lightwindow hidden" rel="SU[Future] title="my caption"><img src="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/side1.jpg" height="100" width="100" /></a>

<a href="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/side2.jpg" class="lightwindow hidden" rel="SU[Future] title="my caption"><img src="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/side2.jpg" height="100" width="100" /></a>

<a href="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/final.jpg" onFocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()" class="lightwindow hidden" rel="SU[Future] title="my caption"><img src="http://bytes.com/images/other/futureSu/final.jpg" height="100" width="100" /></a>

<a href="flash/SnowDrivingFail.mov" class="lightwindow" params="lightwindow_width=340,lightwindow_height=260" title="vid">mp4 vid</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript folder contains:
effects.js, lightwindow.js, prototype.js, scriptaculous.js

Ok, if I copy all the gallery.html code into my main index page it all works, also if I run Gallery.html by it self, the javascript also works... Thus providing it's not an error with gallery.html
Images, etc all BODY content displays correctly when called from index.html (just not the javascript) (i even tried moving the scripts around, into index.html, i tried moving scripts from header to body, but none of them work)

But the error is within the DIV containing the changeable content. And not loading the javascript from other pages.

Please Help someone to get my main page to run the external javascript?

p.s. i uploaded my site, hoping to make it easier for you guys:
p.s.s. i think the error is due to the img-links on index.html not seeing the external scripts; there is no event handler attached to the images. (but what do i do, help me someone :( )

index2.html (click Gallery at top, and choose image (See error, page is redirected instead of javascript call from other html): mediaproject-su.netne.net/index2.html

Gallery.html (to prove the JS works directly, works fine here): mediaproject-su.netne.net/Gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

The page you are AJAXing into your document is not going into another frame so it would not need to look to '.parent' to reference scripts on any of the document. That is unless, you are really AJAXing into an iFrame, then that's a different story.

Comment: Im AJAXing into a div.. Hmm I dont want to use frames, because I have had major trouble with them, I actually tried using frames to split up header/content to prevent header refresh, but I couldnt fix all these scrollbar issues, and the main problem there is no MASTER SCROLLBAR to controll them all, only individual scrolls. \n How else could I look to reference scripts. \n Also is there any other way for me to achieve the effect which inc. javascript: Header/Content (with only content refresh,because header contains sound later, which I dont want to be refreshed everytime someone changes page)

Comment: p.s. I tried adding the <scripts> from gallery.html into index2.html but alas it dodesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your gallery page will have an event to check when the page has loaded to get your gallery functions working. Even if the ajax returns the javascript, you will then need to call any setup functions on the changed dom once it has successfully been inserted into your div